# Swift: lazy population of a collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, lazy-loading

I'm learning Swift, and writing a little app showing a collection view with images. It's not working and the images are never being displayed. I am seeing strange behavior in `collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath`: when I lazily load the image to display in the cell and call `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier()` the second time, it returns a different cell. This happens before I scroll the collection view, so cell reuse shouldn't be a problem. Here is my code:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionCell"
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath:indexPath) as! ImageCollectionCell

        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

        cell.countLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)"

        let imageIndex = XKCDClient.sharedInstance.totalCount - indexPath.row - 1
        println("loading image # \(imageIndex)")
        XKCDClient.sharedInstance.loadComic(imageIndex, completion: { (comicData) -> Void in

            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath:indexPath) as? ImageCollectionCell {
                println("got image # \(imageIndex)")
                cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                if(comicData.image != nil) {
//                    cell.imageView.image = comicData.image // (1)

                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder") // (2)
                    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
                }
            }
            else {
                println("cell \(imageIndex) already reused");
            }
        })

        return cell
    }
```

What happens:

- the callback block gets called for each index path
- the `UIImage` object is correctly passed into the callback block
- No changes to the cell inside the callback seem to have any effect (including setting the background color)
- the cell returned by `collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier()` inside the callback is different from the cell returned in the beginning of the method. That seems to be the root of the problem.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call `dequeuReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` again in the callback closure, but call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` instead. Note: when you set the image in the cell, you have to do it in the main thread:

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
     cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionCell"
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ImageCollectionCell
    cell.imageView.image = nil
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    cell.countLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row+1)"
    let imageIndex = XKCDClient.sharedInstance.totalCount - indexPath.row - 1
    XKCDClient.sharedInstance.loadComic(imageIndex, completion: { (comicData) -> Void in
         if let img = comicData.image {
             // Note: Set image in the main thread
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                  cell.imageView.image = img
             }
         } else {
            println("No image in comicData")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                  cell.imageView.image = nil
             }
         }
    })

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does cause an image to show in the cell, but this code also has a problem: it often displays an image after the cell has been recycled. Which means that the images get displayed in the wrong cells. That is actually the reason why I am getting the cell the 2nd time in the callback.

Comment: Yes, you can either use an abstraction allows invalidating the callbacks when cell is reused (for example [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures)) or you can just call  tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath inside the closure. You should not dequeue a new cell.

Comment: OK, I know what my mistake was. In the callback, I was dequeueing the cell again, instead of calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. I bet that's it. If you want to update your answer with this advice, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, updated the answer. I kept the mention that you have to set image in the main thread. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, as I understand it, the callback is executed on the main thread without any extra code (it's executed on the thread from where the method call was made, which, for `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, is the main thread).